# Show if $x_n$ is in the zero set, then its limit is in the zero set. Curious about alternative proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | f(x) = 0\}$ be the zero set of $f$. If $x_n \in S$ and $x_n \to x$, show that $x \in S$. I believe I have a proof for this:

Suppose $x_n \in S$. So, $f(x_n) = 0$. But also, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. So,

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. whenever $|x - c| < \delta$, $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

Also, suppose $x_n \to x$. Then,

$\forall \rho > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. whenever $n \geq N$, $|x_n - x| < \rho$.

Let $\delta = \rho$. So,

$|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

But, $f(x_n) = 0$. So,

$|0 - f(x)| = |f(x)| < \epsilon$.

Therefore, since $f$ can be made arbitrarily small, $f(x) = 0$. So, $x \in S$.

Now, I am curious about a possible alternative proof. It would suffice to show that $S$ contains all of its limit points (i.e. that $S$ is closed). So, I consider the complement of $S$.

$S^{c} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | f(x) \neq 0\}$.

Now, I want to show this is open. I'm not very good at the basic topology found in real analysis courses, so if this approach is possible, I am wondering how I could start? I know I want to show

$\forall x \in S^{c}, \exists r > 0$ s.t. $B_{r}(x) \subset S^{c}$. However, I don't feel I know enough about the set to put an open ball in there. Am I allowed to say that since $f(x) \neq 0$, it is also not $0$ on a neighborhood of $x$? Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Pick $x\in S^c$ so $f(x)\ne 0$ and consider a ball $(f(x)-\varepsilon,f(x)+\varepsilon)$ not containing $0$. You can choose $\delta>0$ so that $|x'-x|<\delta$ implies $|f(x')-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. So, $|x'-x|<\delta$ implies $f(x')\ne 0$ and thus $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset S^c$ is open.

Comment: The follows entirely from 1)  If $f$ is continuous and $x_n \to x$ then $f(x_n)\to x$ and from 2) $f(x_n)=0$ for all $x_n$.   (So the question you must ask you self is: what is $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)$ [this is *not* a stumper. It is meant to be *easy*].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topological one-liner proof: $S=f^{-1}\{0\}$ contains all its limit points.

In slightly more detail:

As $f$ is continuous, and $\{0\}$ is (hopefully clearly) closed, $f^{-1}\{0\}$ must also be closed, that is, $S$ is closed. If you’re unsure of this, $f$ is continuous precisely when it pulls back open sets to open sets - taking complements, this means it pulls back closed sets to closed sets.

$S$ is closed and $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subseteq S$ means the limit of the $(x_n)$, if it exists, must also be contained in $S$. $f(x)=0$ follows immediately.

This proof generalises to more than just zero sets, but to any closed sets: it also generalises to more spaces than just $\Bbb R$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense actually! Also, on the subject of Topology, do you have a recommendation for a very basic book that one could reference for help with real analysis? Or is the material best found in analysis book since topology ones go too deep?

Comment: @NolanP I’m afraid not. I learnt topology from Royden’s real analysis, which I recommend for its content - but I would not call it especially easy

Answer (score 1):

You can say $f$ is not 0 on a neighbor of $x$ by setting $\epsilon=|f(x)|/2$ and obtaining $\delta$.
(I feel this approach is simpler.)

Comment: How would you go about obtaining $\delta$? Would you just choose $\delta = \epsilon$ to get a neighborhood? I see why I can now say $f$ is not $0$ on a a neighborhood, so that makes sense! I accepted the other answer, but this is still a good one!

Comment: No, we cannot obtain $\delta$ explicitly, but we only know it exists by the assumption that $f$ is continuous.